# How to find gprs strenght?

Tags: android

I am developing one app related to wi-fi,gprs.

I want to check in two conditions ,

1)if wifi is connected i am getting signel strength and do my work based on strength

2)at the same thing i want to get gprs strength also.

If any one has idea please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an instance of `WifiManager`, then call `isWifiEnabled()`

```
WifiManager wifi = your_context.getSystemService(your_context.WIFI_SERVICE);
boolean wifiEnabled = wifi.isWifiEnabled();
```

You should be able to scan for networks using `startScan()`, then call `getScanResults()`. The scan results contain signal strength info for each network. For more see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

I think for GPRS you can get an instance of ConnectivityManager and ask for info on the mobile data connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = your_context.getSystemService(your_context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
NetworkInfo nw = cm.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_MOBILE)
```

This will tell you whether you have a data connection or not. I'm not sure how to get signal strength, but I'm sure you'll figure it out if you read some of the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Comment: No use of what the info u provide.ok